# Append iframe to div without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, refresh

I have a html structure like:

```
<div id="bar">
    <iframe id="foo"></iframe>
    <iframe id="foo2"></iframe>
</div>
```

Each iframe has javaScript running inside it.

Now: I need to add another element...  `<iframe id="foo3"></iframe>` to the end of the div without foo & foo2 from refreshing. I thought jQueries.append() was the way to do this, but this still refreshes the original iframes (Which resets the javaScript inside the already existing iframes).

Any tips/ideas? Thanks

Comment: On which browser do you see this behaviour, using `append()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will be the code

```
document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML += '<iframe id="foo3"></iframe>';
```

Not sure if it will refresh the other iframes